# cant use audio.play inside useEffect (react hooks)

Tags: reactjs, audio, react-hooks, playback

i have a component which plays audio on few different occasions all and all of them work fine with the same function `audio.play()` however the 1 time i have it inside useEffect it dosent work.

this is my code:

```
import ring from '../assets/ring.mp3';

let audio = new Audio(ring);

useEffect(()=> {
    audio.play();
  }, [relativeEndDate])
```

this is my error:

```
Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
    at L (index.js:1)
    at Y (index.js:1)
    at index.js:1
    at index.js:1
    at l (index.js:1)
L @ index.js:1
Y @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
l @ index.js:1
HomePage.js:352 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update latest!**

This answer has many mistakes. Please refer to the answer above/below it to see a working one.

**Update!**

I dug deeper to understand that the error is due to the browser blocking the audio play, even when it's ok to play. The end-user **must interact with the page** before the audio can be played. Below I have updated the code to one that works without error. Alas, the audio didn't play, maybe because I'm using an external source.

Original answer

`useEffect` is a Hook to execute anything once the DOM has been updated with the changes to props and states. The first time the callback provided to the `useEffect` is called is equivalent to `componentDidMount` from the class implementation.

Because of this by the time you try to play the audio, it may not be ready yet, and by the look of the error, the user has not interacted with the page yet.

We can take advantage of the `canplaythrough` event on audio to determine when it's ready to play the audio. Furthermore since `new Audio` returns an HTML element object we will have to use it with `useRef`

import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

```
const url =
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/01_-_Vivaldi_Spring_mvt_1_Allegro_-_John_Harrison_violin.ogg";

export default function Test() {
  const [play, setPlay] = useState(false);
  const audioEl = useRef(new Audio(url));

  useEffect(() => {
    const audio = audioEl.current;
    const onPlay = () => audio.play();

    if (audio && play) {
      audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", onPlay);
    }

    return () => {
      if (audio) {
        audio.pause(); // to enable garbage collection
        audio.removeEventListener("canplaythrough", onPlay);
      }
    };
  }, [play]);

  const onStart = () => {
    setPlay(true);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={onStart}>Start page/game (interact)</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Finally don't forget to return a callback to remove the listener when the component is unloaded.

Comment: this dosent work at all. further more you removed the state i was following with useEffect and replaced it with audioEl.current which is not good. but also when copy pasting your code it dosent even work

Comment: @Nitai, I have updated the code to one that no longer throws errors. It turns out the user must interact with the page before the audio can be played.

Comment: i need the audio to be played when relativeEndDate changes. this does not happen in your code

Comment: Yes, then then add that to the dependency array along with play, `[play, relativeEndDate]`.

Comment: still dosent work. your example have a button which i definatly dont want according to my code. i jsut want sound to be played when relativeEndDate changes. no button no anything.

Comment: The button only imply an user interaction. You can listen to a document click event instead to set the flag, which in turn will trigger play. The rest of the setup for the useEffect is ready.

Comment: i tried to use onStart function and also directly setPlay(true)  inside my useEffect but it didnt work.

Comment: @Nitai, I have added another answer with a working example.

Comment: I'm using your code, it works fine for 1 audio. If I scroll down and see another audio file, it doesn't auto play anymore.

Answer (score 0):

@Nitai, I'm sorry for making so many assumptions when I originally wrote the first answer. The biggest of all is to assume that HTMLAudioElement needs to be saved into a ref. I have corrected my mistake and the following code works (a link to codepen is below it):

```
const url =
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/01_-_Vivaldi_Spring_mvt_1_Allegro_-_John_Harrison_violin.ogg";
function Test() {
  const [relativeEndDate, setRelativeEndDate] = React.useState(false); // for demo only
  const [play, setPlay] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const audio = new Audio(url);
    const onPlay = () => audio.play();

    if (play && relativeEndDate) {
      audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", onPlay);
    }

    return () => {
      if (audio) {
        audio.pause(); // to enable garbage collection
        audio.removeEventListener("canplaythrough", onPlay);
      }
    };
  }, [play, relativeEndDate]);

  const onStart = () => {
    setPlay(true);
    // to demo that only when play and relativeEndDate
    // is true then the audio will play
    setTimeout(() => setRelativeEndDate(true), 1000);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={onStart}>Start page/game (interact)</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Link to demo: https://codepen.io/iamvijaydev/pen/KKWmVve